# C# Double division returning infinity when is not supposed to

Tags: android, xamarin, division, cultureinfo, infinity

I have this code on a Entry completion event:  (Xamarin)

```
if (double.TryParse(txt_MinRate.Text, out double i))
{
    if (i < 0.0 || i > 6.0)
    {
        if (i > 6.0)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Invalid input", "6% is the maximum rate allowed.", "OK");
            txt_MinRate.Text = "6.0";
        }
        else if (i < 0.0)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Invalid input", "Don't worry. There will never be a negative rate", "OH Good");
            txt_MinRate.Text = "0.0";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Settings.MinRate = i / 100.0;
    }
}
```

and the thing is... If I type 0.01 Settings.MinRate is saved with value 0.0001 which is what is expected to happen.

If I type 0.001 in the entry.... Settings.MinRate is saved with -Infinity.....

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

EDIT:

To be fair Settings.MinRate is not quite a simple double... I think...
This is in Settings.cs file:

```
        private const string txt_MinRateyKey = "txt_MinRate_Key";
        private static readonly double txt_MinRateDefault = 0.0;
        public static double MinRate
        {
            get => AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(txt_MinRateyKey, txt_MinRateDefault);
            set => AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(txt_MinRateyKey, value);
        }
```

EDIT 2:

I just added a simple line of: double x = i / 100; right after Settings.MinRate = i / 100;

sorry for the last edit... my bad... the result was correct for the double x value... 1E-05... So the problem seems to be the Settings Plugin...

Comment: What type is Settings.MinRate?

Comment: it is also a double.  I edited my question with the response

Comment: when you say "saved" do you mean when it's actually saved/loaded using the Settings plugin, or when the MinRate calculation is actually done?

Comment: it's the result right after the breakpoint calculates Settings.MinRate = i / 100.0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Settings Plugin that I'm using...

I created bug report on the plugin github and it was quickly fixed in version 3.1.1 of the Plugin.

It now works as expected! :)

Thanks for the help!